# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' when using list of lists

Tags: python, list

I've been struggling with this problem for a while and could use some help. I'm trying to append values to a list from a list of lists. I get a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`. I understand the that I'm trying to pass a list of lists to another list but I can't find a solution.

I start off by reading two separate lists that are then combined to make a list of those lists. I use this list of lists to parse through and remove specific values using the `is_number` function.

I originally had `float(s)` and then tried `list(map(float(s)))` but get the same error. I have also tried to alter `a_data, b_data` from being a list but my actual dataset is a `df.values.tolist()` so it will always be in list form.

So instead of:

```
a_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]
```

My actual dataset is read:

```
a_data = df[['AB','AC','AD','AE']].values.tolist()
```

So the input will always be in list from. The rest of the code is the same. An example dataset is derived from:

```
import random
from functools import partial
one_sample = partial(random.sample, range(80), 20)

a_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)] #Makes a list
b_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)] #Makes another list

data = [a_data,b_data] #Combine those lists to from one
```

The actual final list of lists that I'm working with looks like this:

```
data = [[45.10031842, 'nan', -3.5165602060000003, 41.79799446, -24.616148100000004, -22.98303729, 'nan', 3.51273869, 28.44337707, 11.06472095, -35.54419066, 'nan', 45.73116662, 29.26475119, -40.68655635, 6.110571001, 'nan', -45.11483157, 3.001018117, -1.052283362, 38.61536724],
[65.74835477, 'nan', 73.73594438, 61.90991549, 67.06663915, 77.13941436, 'nan', 93.94853726, 56.51826591, 70.20955909999999, 73.07962202, 'nan', 69.78626105, 73.34402753, 64.72901307, 70.90387539, 'nan', 70.94140139, 42.78164288, 61.77394225, 72.07455255],
[45.15534694, 'nan', -3.3464740539999998, 41.78674915, -24.58808435, -23.02517617, 'nan', 3.5287456269999997, 28.38370261, 10.99883442, -35.47750429, 'nan', 45.85988623, 29.30369084, -40.77004615, 6.1017473010000005, 'nan', -45.29294224, 3.0151219680000003, -0.9927861370000001, 38.71278829],
[65.7684248, 'nan', 73.69043192, 61.69908417, 67.18671591, 77.17029694, 'nan', 93.89646426, 56.5427544, 70.19822793, 73.1451771, 'nan', 69.793868, 73.19566664, 64.95606388, 70.91007366, 'nan', 71.04051167, 42.83526579, 61.82365038, 72.11546062],
[45.23761992, 'nan', -3.1705542469999997, 41.78674915, -24.56060698, -23.05487575, 'nan', 3.5493760489999997, 28.31338862, 10.91910555, -35.41010968, 'nan', 45.85988623, 29.35832821, -40.83631919, 6.095069866, 'nan', -45.50045784, 3.042026157, -0.908282198, 38.79647675],
[65.7834979, 'nan', 73.63024857, 61.69908417, 67.31838918, 77.19810461, 'nan', 93.83429634, 56.58563081, 70.20044679, 73.19935612, 'nan', 69.793868, 73.03211884, 65.18572736, 70.90862232, 'nan', 71.14518241, 42.91278516, 61.89316922, 72.15835354]]


def is_number(s): #This function removes nan values from my list
    try:
        if str(s).lower() != "nan":
         list(map(float(s))) #Error is in this line
         return True
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return False

animate = [[],[]]

animate[0].append([float(_) for _ in data if is_number(_)]) #Error in this line
animate[1].append([float(_) for _ in data if is_number(_)]) #Error in this line
```

Comment: Probably you want `list(map(float, s))`

Comment: Same error @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Looks like "_" here is a list.

```
animate[0].append([map(float, _) for _ in data]) 
animate[1].append([map(float, _) for _ in data])
```

Comment: Can yo post the list 'data'?

Comment: I've uploaded the first 6 lists. So 3 from each. Using your code and changing `(float(s))` to `(float, s)` gives me another TypeError: `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`

Comment: @Punter345; Updated solution. Can you try now?

Comment: Same error sorry @Rakesh. `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`. I also need to run the data through the is_number function as it removes all `nan`values.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided makes `data` a list of two lists. This is because you define `a_data` and `b_data` as two separate lists, then put them into `data`. What you should do instead is make an empty list, then call `extend()` on that list with `a_data` as parameter (then `b_data`). So:

```
data = []
data.extend (a_data)
data.extend (b_data)
```

As for the `is_number` function, I'm having a hard time following what it does (especially calling `map`), so I'll recommend a simpler one:

```
def is_num (num):
    try: float (num)
    except ValueError: return False
    else: return True
```

Comment: I didn't mention the `is_number` function because it wasn't directly related to the problem and didn't want to add confusion. My actual dataset has `nan` values and this removes those before appending to the final list. I like the `.extend`function though. I still get the same error

Comment: In the first part I mentioned that you would need to change `data` from being a list of lists to one long list. This can be done with the `+` operator, as mentioned above. And don't worry about the `is_num` function, I just included it to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your `data` ends up being a list of lists of lists ([a_data, b_data] where each itself is each a list of lists). Thus in your last two lines

```
animate[0].append([float(_) for _ in data if is_number(_)])
```

the `_` is actually still a list of lists, where I think you wanted it to be the list of values. My guess is that in the line that says

```
data = [a_data,b_data]
```

you actually wanted something more like

```
data = a_data+b_data
```

though this would still give you a list of lists. Would probably need a bit more clarification to fully answer the question.

---

I always find it easier to do a list comprehension than the map function. I don't know if one is actually *better*, but `[float(x) for x in data]` seems more intuitive than `list(map(float, data))`

---

One more note: Though the syntax is valid, it's standard to use `_` when we *don't care what `_` is.* However, if you are actually using it to represent something you are going to use, it's more standard to give it a normal variable name.